# Sharepont List alerts get fired twice

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert

i have set alert on list item "AssignedTo" (A task is assigned to Me). It was working fine since last 1.5 year. But now suddenly it fires twice. So all of the users assigned Task get alert twice. I dont know why it happens. how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you added a workflow to it recently?

Comment: no..i have not added any workflow to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Users was getting alert twice because my one of colleagues has deployed event receiver that is used to set alert for users. So some of the users have alerts set twice for the same list. I removed unnecessary alerts and asked my colleague to modify his code.

Regards,

Dhaval

Comment: "one of my colleagues has deployed event receiver" -- You guys will be in big trouble if you don't develop and adhere to a strict governance regime about change management and testing new functionality. If one user can deploy a solution that breaks functionality elsewhere, how can you ever expect a stable farm?